# Fireworks on Yom Tov

Tags: halacha, yom-tov

Happy coming New Year all!

I recently pondered whether igniting fireworks using an existing flame on yom tov would be permissible given that fireworks are “universally appreciated.” Given that I’ve seen people smoke hookah on yom tov, I don’t see why fireworks would be prohibited. Is there any reason why fireworks should be prohibited?

Comment: I'm not sure smoking hookah is actually permitted. People seem to extrapolate from smoking, but a) smoking is not the same and b) even with smoking many major poskim such as Rav Belsky and Rav Asher Weiss say it is assur on Yom Tov. And I know a lot of people do not appreciate fireworks.

Comment: In addition, the Jewish New Year is nothing like the non-Jewish new year. It is not a time of celebration, but rather a solemn day of rededicating our lives to our Creator, and a Day of Judgement. Would you let off fireworks on the day of a major court case? Our sages teach that the Books of Life and Death are open, and it is decided where each person's name will be written. FIreworks are not appropriate.

Comment: There used to be a *minhag* for people to set off fireworks on Simchas Torah. Presumably the reason this should be *mutar* is for the same reason you can smoke on Yom Tov.

Answer (score 5):

Before answering, I would like to remind all askers and readers that for **practical matters**, all questions should be directed to a competent Rabbi. That being said, let me quote the חיי אדם סי׳
קנג:

> ואף על גב שמצוה גדולה לשמוח אבל אסור להבעיר פולווער וראוי למחות ולגעור
> בעושין כן אבל מותר לקבוע שפופרת מלאה פולווער בתוך הנר בערב יום טוב
> אע"פ שהנר כבה על ידו (מגן אברהם סימן תקי"ד):

> Despite the fact that it is an extremely important *mitzvah* to be joyous [on Simcha Torah], it is prohibited to light "powder" [gunpowder], and one should prevent and protest those who do. It is, however, permitted to place a vial of gunpowder in a candle on *erev Yom Tov*, despite the fact that it will cause the candle to go out [when the gunpowder explodes].

It seems based on this that lighting a firecracker would be prohibited, but that you can set one up before Yom Tov to go off.

Again, practical questions should be asked to a Rav.

Comment: Note that from the Magen Avraham there it seems that one is allowed to put the gunpowder in to an existing candle on Yom Tov itself - so it seems like they argue on this point